# UIbutton stretchable

Tags: uibutton

I have 2 images for UIbutton (1 for normal state and 1 for highlited state). When the button is highlited the height of button increases(as per image size) . I want that height of button should increase  only from top and not from bottom. I mean it should stretch from top .is it possible ? if yes ,how ?

Answer (score 0):

```
myButton.contentMode = UIViewContentModeBottom;
```

The above line of code should tell the button to align your images to the bottom of the bounds.  If that does not work, you will have to implement `drawRect:` in a subclass of UIButton and draw the image yourself.